# How do I create a mock context for grpc unit testing (python)

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, grpc-python, pytest-mock

In normal grpc communications, grpc automatically creates a context to go with the request.  How do I create a mock context to pass with my unit test call, so my servicing function has an object to manipulate?

Currently I have the code skip the context calls if it receives a NoneType as context, but that is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the magic mock library [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). And mock over the client RPC multicallable object `grpc.UnaryUnaryMultiCallable` (see [ref](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.UnaryUnaryMultiCallable)), so it returns your response and context. This object is generated by our ProtoBuf plugin, and sits in the `foo_pb2_grpc.py` file.

Comment: I ended up just creating my own context class with the matching methods.  When I grok the mock, I will probably do a better job.  I believe your solution would work, so I'll mark it as an answer.